# If condition1 and 2 are true (cell compare to a range of cells) than show a specific value in excel

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2013

I want to create a function when two comparative conditions are True than a cell takes a specific value.

This is the Function i am trying to use:

```
=IF(AND("City"="List of cities","Product"="List of products")*TRUE,Cell Value,NA())
```

When i compare a cell with another cell, the formula works fine but when i compare a cell with a range of cells the result is False.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at using `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`, in combination with `ISERROR`

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH("City","List of cities",0))=FALSE,ISERROR(MATCH("Product","List of products",0))=FALSE),"Cell Value",NA())
```

Comment: `ISERROR(MATCH("City","List of cities",0))=FALSE`(1) is pretty unintuitive.. Same for `ISERROR(MATCH("Product","List of products",0))=FALSE`(2). Instead I'd do `XOR( (1) , (2) )` which gives `XOR(ISERROR(MATCH("City","List of cities",0)),ISERROR(MATCH("Product","List of products",0)))` I would suggest **never** using `= False` or `= True`.

Comment: @guitarthrower Why would I make an answer with a modified answer of someone else? That would be stealing IMO.

Comment: It's not modified. You use a different formula and different approach. Not stealing. Take credit for your ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `List Of Cities` and `List Of Products` are lists composed as named ranges

You can use `CountIF`

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(List_Of_Cities,"City"),COUNTIF(List_Of_Products,"Product")),"Cell Value","NA")
```